# Show that no set $S$ is equinumerous with $P(S)$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Looking for a proof check. I've written out the argument as it reads most easily to my own eyes.

Let $S$ be a set and suppose by contradiction that $\exists f:S \to P(S)$ with f surjective. Define $B = \{x \in A: x \notin f(n)\}$. $f$ surjective $\implies B = f(x_0)$ for some $x_0$. $x \in B \iff x \notin f(x)$ but $B = f(n_0)$ so $n_0 \in f(n_0) \iff n_0 \notin f(n_0)$ which is a contradiction. Therefore $\nexists f$.

Comment: Missing a bunch of definitions, hence hard to figure out what's happening. What are $A$ and $n$?

Comment: Why did you write $x \in f(x) \iff x \in B$?  Where did you get that from?

Comment: @stochasticboy321Typos, fixed.

Comment: @user46944 If $x$ is in the $P(S) $ (which is $f(x)$) then it must also be in $B$ because $B$ contains elements of $S$.

Comment: Where in your proof did you use the fact that $f$ is surjective?

Comment: @Chris $B$ is the subset of $S$ such that each element $x$ is *not* in its image.  So it doesn't make sense to say $x \in f(x) \iff x\in B$.  Because this isn't true.  $x \not \in f(x) \iff x \in B$ is true.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger In the supposition. We then show that it cannot be.

Comment: @user46944 Since $B$ contains elements of $S$ any element of $P(S)$ must be in $B$. This is the contradiction.

Comment: @Chris Explain why "since $B$ contains elements of $S$, any element of $P(S)$ must be in $B$".  I'm not following why this is true.

Comment: @user46944 Aha I see your point.

Comment: Ok I believe I have the correct edits.